Git Push Rejected by GitHub repository
HI All While i am trying to Push the Code into git hub Repository getting below error can any one please help
 git push -u origin main
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 

Solution for git issue

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+non-fast-forward

make sure you have the branch "main" in Github.
Have you tried git push -f -u origin main to push force ?
